# EGit did not push layout files

Tags: eclipse, jira, egit

I created repo in JIRA and pushed all my android project file but I figured out that layout files didn't push 
I use EGit 3.3 with eclipse 4.2 
also  it doesn't show any indicator for file status

EDIT:
all folders in res folder doesn't update in git repo and I don't know why

Comment: Are those layout files perhaps included in a local or global .gitignore file? The fact that no indicator is shown points towards this conclusion...

Comment: but I didn't create any gitignore files also indicator not exist for any file or folder for project

Comment: When you say you created a repo in JIRA (an issue tracker), I assume you have a git repo, a JIRA instance, and are using the git integration Plug-in for JIRA. Where exactly do you push your code to, and where do you see that the files haven't been pushed?

Comment: company i work for created private repo for project in JIRA and i pushed files to it but my co worker try to pull it and he didn't find any layout files and I took a look to Source tab in JIRA and i didn't find any layout files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EGIT by Default doesn't track res folder and so will not push it to server 
Also if you try to add this folder to Index by mouse right click and from context menu to click Add to Index this will not work too 
The Solution That worked with me is to add it from command line (or terminal as i did)
by run this command `git add *` when you in your git directory 
hope this will help someone